# How to position boxes like a posterboard with CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Trying to make a page of boxes that looks like this posterboard layout: http://try.time.ly/

Right now, all of my boxes have fixed widths and resizable heights (depending on the length of content/pictures). However, I can't get them to stack like they do in the above layout. Any suggestions?

This is what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/SEe42/1/ I was hoping that the max-height attribute would push the boxes to the next column over to the right, but they just keep stacking from the bottom.

html:

```
<!doctype html>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="panel">
            voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo ino
        </div>
        <div class="panel">
            voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque i
        </div>
        <div class="panel">
            voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo  accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam 
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

css:

```
.container {
    width: 500px;
    max-height: 300px;
}
.panel {     
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
    border-style: solid;    
}
```

Comment: http://packery.metafizzy.co, http://masonry.desandro.com, don't remake what others have already made, just use what is already out there.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans wow that's just what i was looking for. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/7n2YH/)**

Responsive, css only solution using CSS column properties

html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="panel">voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo ino</div>
    <div class="panel">voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque i</div>
    <div class="panel">voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam</div>
    <div class="panel">voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam</div>
    <div class="panel">voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam</div>
    <div class="panel">>voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo ino</div>
    <div class="panel">voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque i</div>
</div>
```

css

```
body {
    font: 1em/1.67'Open Sans', Arial, Sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    background: #e9e9e9;
}
.container {
    margin: 1.5em;
    padding: 0;
    -moz-column-gap: 1.5em;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1.5em;
    column-gap: 1.5em;
    font-size: .85em;
}
.panel {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 0 0 1.5em;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 0 #ccc;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 400px) {
    .container {
        -moz-column-count: 2;
        -webkit-column-count: 2;
        column-count: 2;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {
    .container {
        -moz-column-count: 3;
        -webkit-column-count: 3;
        column-count: 3;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    .container {
        -moz-column-count: 4;
        -webkit-column-count: 4;
        column-count: 4;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1100px) {
    .container {
        -moz-column-count: 5;
        -webkit-column-count: 5;
        column-count: 5;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to add `float: left` in your .panel

[click](http://jsfiddle.net/2gRW3/) here for demo

Comment: That doesn't work, there is still whitespace between boxes (vertically) if the boxes aren't uniform in size.